# In Opencart how do I make cart weight round up to whole kg?

Tags: opencart

I need to make Opencart round the total weight of the cart up to the next whole kg and calculate shipping on that. So for example if my cart weights 4.3kg I need the cart to calculate shipping on 5kg.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this using the `ceil()` function in PHP.
The `ceil()` function is used to round fractions up, thereby returning the next highest integer value by rounding up if necessary.

Usage example:

```php
echo ceil(4.3);    //  5
echo ceil(4.9);    //  5
echo ceil(-4.5);   // -3
```

If you are getting the value using MySQL statement then you will do something like
`SELECT CEIL(4.3);` which will round the number up to 5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I go about implemeting that in opencart?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are after (Weight based shipping: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=142&t=30714  and this for setting up the GeoZone: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=7099

Comment: @guru If you want to only use the rounded value for calculating the shipping costs then it is enough to change the shipping option's controller that is weight-based. If you want to also change the displayed values (e.g. in cart, checkout summary, etc.), then You'd need to change also those controllers.

Comment: I dont think that will work because I only want the total rounded up. So if there are 5 products that are 4.1 kilos, I want the total to be 21kg. Is that what you mean?